# Handling Issues in a agile environment?

Tags: manual-testing, test-management, test-design, agile-testing, scrum

Right now I'm almost tormented by answering the following question:

> "How do we handle our errors and issues in an agile environment?"

Scrum is a framework that does not directly dictate how to handle errors. The direct answer would be to treat bugs as `Product Backlog Items` that should be included in the `Product Backlog`. If the `Product Owner` rates their priority as very high, then they will be considered by the development team at the next sprint.

#### Questions:

- But is this the only or the right way?
- So how should you deal with the mistakes in an agile development?

Comment: Voting for closing because it seems a duplicate of "How bug prioritization works in agile projects vs non agile". Refer to the accepted answer https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/38904/12740

Answer (score 0):

See also [bug prioritization in agile projects.](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/31865/in-an-agile-work-environment-what-kind-of-work-should-be-classified-as-a-bug-to)

> The direct answer would be to treat bugs as Product Backlog Items that should be included in the Product Backlog

Thats a pretty good answer imho, but as stated here

[How bug prioritization works in agile projects vs non agile](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/38902/how-bug-prioritization-works-in-agile-projects-vs-non-agile) you need to make sure your team has a common understanding what a bug is.